# Why is Viewbox breaking layout in Grid with equally spaced rows/columns?

Tags: wpf, grid, viewbox

Put it simply, I have one Grid with three equally high rows and two buttons. I want to have first button in the first row, then second row empty and finally second button in the third row. This way I get spacing between buttons that is of relative size. I need this rather than hard-coding absolute margin values. So here is the XAML for that:

```
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0">Button 1</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Row="2">Button 2</Button>
                </Grid>
```

Works great! Now additional feature I need is to have everything scalable, so I put it in Viewbox:

```
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0">Button 1</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Row="2">Button 2</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
```

And suddenly layout is broken. I get the scaling provided by Viewbox but I don't get empty space between buttons. So two questions:

1. Why is Viewbox breaking things here?
2. How can I workaround this? I need flexibility so imagine I can have arbitrary number of buttons that can be separated by arbitrary number of empty rows/columns in a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition 
                        MinHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,
                                   ElementName=MyButton1}"
                        Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MyButton1">Button 1</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2">Button 2</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Strictly assuming the buttons are of all same height.

And for reason why this happens check this... http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/403562/wpf-grid-layout-is-broken-when-put-in-viewbox

Answer (score 0):

Viewbox doesn't work well with percents. In my opinion, I don't recommend the use of Viewbox to "group" all the elements. You should use the Viewbox just for the button text:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="LightGray">
                        <Viewbox>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}">Button 1</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}">Button 2</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```